# Position of Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

How do i move Texbox inside of a Grid's Row 20px from the left? I don't care if it is done in code or in XAML. I know it seems like a simple solution, but can't find any property to do this.

Comment: Why do you use a Grid? instead you could use a Dock Panel which is perfect for your problem

Comment: have you tried Left option ?

Comment: Because my app is long and 99% finished, i just need to move 1 textbox 20px from the left. Now changing to Dock Panel seems like useless thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Margin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) property:

```
<TextBox Margin="20,0,0,0" />
```

Comment: This works, but ignores the MinWidth property.

Comment: Margins aren't part of the element size: they are outside. Try to use `20,0,-20,0` to get the behavior you're looking for.